# iOS Old MPL SDK, Where's the download?

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm trying to start implementing MPL into a new app. 
I only found links to the current Paypal iOS SDK , but that one is only supported inside the US, so It's not a solid option for me.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Trying to find a download for the classic MPL SDK but their website is not very helpful.
Would appreciate any assistance on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PayPal is replacing the Mobile Payments Library with the iOS/Android SDK.  You should be able to download the SDK from the the github site [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/tags).  Non-US developers, can continue to use the MPL and you should be able to find it [here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/).

Comment: Ah ha! That second link was what I was looking for. THank you very much! Is there an estimation when the new SDK could be used worldwide?

Comment: I don't have any date as of yet.